# Which functions are called once widget disappear?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

what is widget lifecycle ? which function is called first?

Comment: Some more details please...

Comment: i load data from webservice for widget in viewdidload for the first run it works successfully but when i tab notification view then return back to widget view nothing called ! i want viewdidload to be called again.

Answer (score 2):

`viewDidLoad()` is called exactly once in a views lifecycle.

Depending on your needs, use:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // do stuff you want to do before the view actually appears
}
```

or:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    // do stuff you want to do when the view appears
}
```

For detailed information regarding a `UIView`s lifecycle visit [Apples Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller)